# Eloquent model with table name dynamically set breaks after queued (Laravel 5.8)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8, laravel-queue

I'm already setting dynamically the table name on a model, but it breaks when queued due to model serialization I guess.

**I need that value to persist.**

I need to be able to set job to queues, that, given a table name, get all the rows in it, process them one by one until no more rows left.
However, this table may change its name but not the structure, so I'm using a model to read/update every row.

However, I've found that AFTER sending the job to queue, the table property of the model gets reverted to the original one, set in the model class.

DataSource.php

```
class DataSource extends Model
{
    protected $table = '';
}
```

MyJob.php

```
public function processTable(string $table)
{
    $datasource = new DataSource();
    $datasource->setTable($table);
    logger('COUNT: '.$datasource->count());

    $datasource::chunk(3, function(...){
        ...
    });
}
```

User Input: **my_table**

Test **before** `::dispatch`:

`dump($datasource->getTable())` shileds `my_table`

`dump('COUNT: '.$datasource->count());` shields the correct rows count

When running the queue job:

```
local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '' (SQL: select * from `` order by ``.`id` asc limit 3 offset 0)...
```

As you can see, the `$table` property of the model gets missed in the [de]serialization of the model at any point in time after being dispatched to the database.

I'm not absolutely sure about my hypothesis. I'd need someone to confirm or rectify me if this is really what is going on.

**The need is: persist the right table name to be processed by the job when pulled from the queue.**

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing the `table` property within the job before dispatching?  This is required for any data you want to pass through when using the queue.  The following example worked for me.

/App/Jobs/DataSourceJob.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\DataSource;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class DataSourceJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    // this is where the table name will be stored
    protected $table;

    public function __construct($table)
    {
        // store the table name prior to entering queue
        $this->table = $table;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // retrieve the table name when the job runs
        $table = $this->table;

        $datasource = new DataSource();
        $datasource->setTable($table);
        logger('COUNT: '.$datasource->count());

        $datasource::chunk(3, function() {
            //
        });
    }
}
```

Test it out.

```php
$table = '...';

dispatch(new DataSourceJob($table));
```